# Displaying both plt.show() images as Figure 1, Figure 2 at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-image

Running the following code, I am unable to display both images at the same time in separate windows, or go from figure1 to figure2 with the arrow button.
Currently I am able to get figure2, only when I close figure1.

I have tried the following code to generate separate "figure" labels.

```py
from skimage import data, color, io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rocket = data.rocket()
gray_scale_rocket = color.rgb2gray(rocket)

f1=plt.figure(1)
io.imshow(rocket)
plt.show()

f2=plt.figure(2)
io.imshow(gray_scale_rocket)
plt.show()
```

I expect to see two windows figure1 and figure2 to be viewable at the same time (without needing to close figure1 window first), displaying the rocket image in color and in grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the first call to `plt.show()`, which is blocking (meaning it stops execution until you are done with the window). When you leave only the second one, it will show both figures simultaneously.

The resulting code:

```py
from skimage import data, color, io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rocket = data.rocket()
gray_scale_rocket = color.rgb2gray(rocket)

f1=plt.figure(1)
io.imshow(rocket)

f2=plt.figure(2)
io.imshow(gray_scale_rocket)
plt.show()
```

behaves as you expect.